# ошибка PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе

Tags: python, windows

написал программу, перемещающую файлы в папку, пытаюсь запустить - отказано в доступе. Переконвертировал в exe. открывается консоль и тут же закрывается. Думаю, что опять отказано в доступе. никак не могу решить данную пробелму

Comment: Рекомендую убедится что файл не используется, например этим же скриптом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить приложение от имени администратора.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пробовал уже. не помогло